# Series for the higher derivatives of the Zeta function around S=1 with Stieltjes constants?

Tags: analysis, zeta-functions, exponential-sum

The series for $\zeta'(s)$ about $s=1$ is:

$-(\frac1{(s-1)^2}) -\gamma_1 +\gamma_2(s-1)-\frac12\gamma_3(s-1)^2$....

where $\gamma$ are the Stieltjes constants.

I'm using this series to determine the asymptotic behavior of:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^{1/{(k^{1+\frac1{\sqrt{x}}})}} -1$

Using the series I already have, I can show that the dominant term is x minus the first Stieltjes constant $\gamma_1.$

If I had a similar series for higher derivatives, I could determine if the asymptotic behavior, mainly prove or disprove whether the output exceeds $x+1$.

Does anyone happen to know the higher order derivative series for the Zeta function close to 1 like above, or a resource?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\zeta^{(n)}(1+\frac1{\sqrt{x}})}{n!}$ doesn't converge for $x > 1$

Comment: Yes, but Im going to remove that as its a detour.

Comment: Why don't you just differentiate once more: $\zeta''(s)=\frac{2}{(s-1)^3}+\gamma_2-\gamma_3(s-1)+..., \zeta'''(s)=-\frac{6}{(s-1)^4}-\gamma_3+...$ and so on ?

Comment: I'm sorry the answer was so obvious! I thought there might have been a catch. Thank you.

Comment: Hi R.J. we both wrote programs for A000146 :)